# non-removable singularities of a function are essential singularities of the composition function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, singularity-theory

Let $f$ be a non-constant enrire function on $\mathbb{C}$ such  that $f(z+i)=f(z)$ for all $z$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $C$ and $z_0\in U$. Let $g:U\setminus\{z_0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. If $z_0$ is a non-removable singularity of $g$, prove that $z_0$ is an essential singularity if $f\circ g$.

How to prove?

In the case that $g$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$, let $g(z)=\sum_{k=-m}^\infty b_k (z-z_0)^k$. since $f$ is periodic hence not a polynomial, $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. Hence 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(g(z))&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(g(z))^n\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\sum_{k=-m}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k)^n\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k_1,\cdots,k_n\geq -m} a_nb_{k_1}\cdots b_{k_n}(z-z_0)^{k_1+\cdots +k_n}\\
&=&\sum_{p=-\infty}^\infty(\sum_{\sum_{j=1}^n k_j=p,n\in\mathbb{N},k_j\geq -m}a_nb_{k_1}\cdots b_{k_n})(z-z_0)^p.
\end{eqnarray}
How to prove that there are infinite many terms such that the coefficients $\sum_{\sum_{j=1}^n k_j=p,n\in\mathbb{N},k_j\geq -m}a_nb_{k_1}\cdots b_{k_n}$ are nonzero?

Dear Professor, I am still confused. Since $z_0$ is a pole, for any $M>0$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $g(D^*(z_0,\epsilon))\subseteq \{|z|>M\}$ (they may not be equal). $f(\{|z|>M\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. How to obtain $f(g(D^*(z_0,\epsilon))$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: All I can think of at the moment is that g is unbounded near $z_0$, otherwise, you could use Riemann's removable singularities theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor series for $f$ must be an infinite series because the periodicity property guarantees that $f$ is not a polynomial.  Thus, we are done if the singularity of $g$ at $z_0$ is a pole of order $>0$.  Entire functions that are not constant may not omit two points in the image from the complex plane. (This is Picard's theorem.  Its weakening to only say "has dense image" instead of "may not omit two points" is also acceptable.)

The image of every deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ under $f\circ g$ is then dense in $C$.  This is equivalent to the singularity being essential actually, even though Casorati-Weierstrass is only stated usually in one direction.  Think about why.

It seems like I only used the fact that $f$ is not polynomial and yet entire.  Is something wrong with this proof?  It has been years since I last did complex analysis.

Comment: Dear Professor Jeff, how to prove infinitely many terms of the coefficient sequence are nonzero?

Comment: Because otherwise the singularity would be a pole in which case the modulus of $g \circ f $ approaches $\infty$ contrary to the denseness of image in neighborhoods.

Comment: Dear Professor, I am still confused. Since $z_0$ is a pole, for any $M>0$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $g(D^*(z_0,\epsilon))\subseteq \{|z|>M\}$ (they may not be equal). $f(\{|z|>M\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. How to obtain $f(g(D^*(z_0,\epsilon))$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: If $g$ maps every deleted neighborhood onto a dense subset of the complex plane, then since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f\circ g$ maps every deleted neighborhood onto a dense subset of the range of $f$.  Since the range of $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ then actually the range of $f \circ g$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. (I use "range" to mean "image")