# Compute an the index around 0 of e composed with f where f has a non-removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, singularity

Let $f$ have a non-removable singularity at 0, and let $f$ be holomorphic on the punctured disk $B'(0,1)$.

I want to compute Ind$(\exp \circ f \circ \alpha, 0)$ where $\alpha(t) = 1/2 e^{it}$, for $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$.

So I tried just using the definition

Let $\beta(t)= \exp \circ f \circ \alpha$. Since all the functions here are holomorphic on the domain $\beta$ is a piecewise smooth curve. Since $\beta(0)=\beta(2\pi)$ the curve $\beta$ is closed.

\begin{equation}\begin{split}\text{Ind}(\beta,0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\beta \frac{dz}{z-0} &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{f \circ \alpha} \frac{\exp(\zeta)'}{\exp{(\zeta})}d\zeta \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{f \circ \alpha} \frac{\exp(f(\alpha))(f(\alpha))'}{f(\alpha)}d\zeta \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\alpha(0)}^{\alpha(2\pi)} \frac{\exp(f(\alpha))f'(\alpha)\alpha'(t)}{f(\alpha)}dt \end{split}\end{equation}

I've no idea what $f$s values could be so this doesn't look that helpful. Since there's only one singularity, I worked out the Residue theorem too. I used the identity function over the curve $\beta$ \begin{equation}\begin{split}\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\beta z dz &= \text{Ind}(\exp(f(\alpha)),0)\text{Res(e,0)} \\ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} z^2 \Big|_{\beta(0)}^{\beta(2\pi)} &= \text{Ind}(\exp(f(\alpha(t))),0)\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=r} e^z dz. \end{split}\end{equation}

The RHS has an integral I can probably look up in the notes or the internet (is it just $2\pi$?) The LHS should be $0$ since $\beta(0)=\beta(2 \pi)$. So either I made a mistake or this isn't helpful.

The only other thing I tried was using a Laurent series for $f$. That still leaves me in the position of having to integrate the unknown function $f$ over a curve.

The question has a second part too, Show that $\exp \circ f$ does not have a pole at $0$. But I don't think that's related. Also, FYI
[non-removable singularities of a function are essential singularities of the composition function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813264/non-removable-singularities-of-a-function-are-essential-singularities-of-the-com)

Comment: Sorry I think now that this is very easy the only problem is my inexperience. It's true that $\exp(f \circ \alpha)$ is a closed curve, but it's also true that $e^f \circ \alpha$ is a closed curve which is equal to the first and $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(e^f)'}{e^f}dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(e^f)f'}{e^f}dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} f'(z) dz = f(z)\Big|_{z=\alpha(0)}^{z=\alpha{2 \pi}} = 0.$$ It also appears as if this has nothing to do with the second part of the question.

Comment: If you assume that $\exp \circ f$ has a pole then you can use the the principle of the argument to show that $\int_{\alpha(t)} \frac{(e^f)'}{e^f}dz \neq 0.$ It would in fact equal $2 \pi i (-1)$. Since $\exp \circ f$ can not have a pole or a removable singularity (the later is by assumption) then $e^f$ must have an essential singularity by Casorati-Weierstrass.